# iPhone Xcode Project Organization Question

Tags: iphone, xcode, project

- I built a simple iPhone application for a customer
- This will be distributed via iTunes using Ad Hoc Provisioning profile
- I need to build two different executables
- 1) a test application and an 2) official application
- the only differences between the two applications are:
  . the Default.png startup screen
  . some image icons in the application
  . the application icon

how can I organize my xcode project so I can use a single project
for the two applications ?
- do I need to create multiple targets ?
- can I use the same Application name and Provisioning profiles for the two application
  or I need different ones ?
- is it simpler to add a shell script at building start and just personalize the application
  graphics depending on a SWITCH VARIABLE defined in the project ?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same provisioning profile if you set it up as a "wildcard" profile. Do that by setting the application identifier to something along the lines of "com.companyname.*" (the * is the important part).

As for the image switching, you could do that with two targets, and each target having a specific shell script at the beginning of the build process which chooses which image to use.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should create multiple tatgets. That is the easiest way to include different Default.png files.

You sign both versions using a wildcard provisioning profile. Take a look at the Apple provisioning docs.